# file association not working with install4 in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, install4j

I am using the file associations feature in install4j to associate files of a given extension to a launcher.

This is not working when I install on Windows 8.

The associations work properly on other OS versions (Mac OSX, Windows 7, etc), but not on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "Create a file association" actions are after the "Install files" actions, otherwise they will not work if you perform a clean installation (not an update installation).

Comment: They already are.  We first show the "File Associations" dialog, then we have the "Installation" folder, inside the "Installation" folder, the first item is "Install files", and then a few "Create a file association items.  Please note that this problem only happens in Windows 8, it works fine in other OSs.

Comment: What does the .install4j\installation.log file say for these actions?

Comment: It says that the actions executed successfully:

[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.desktop.CreateFileAssociationAction [ID 1169]: Execute action
       Property windows: true
       Property description: Adobe PDF Files
       Property selected: true
       Property extension: pdf
       Property launcherId: 22
       Property mac: true
       Property macIconFile: i4j_extf_11_1lgg176_znjol5.icns
       Property macRole: Viewer
       Property winAdditionalParameters: 
       Property windowsIconFile: i4j_extf_12_1lgg176_1ik53dn.ico

Comment: Property restartFinder: false
       Property persistentProperties: {}
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Execute action successful after 47 ms

Comment: I can send you the full file if you need.

Comment: I can see that there might be problems fighting against Adobe Acrobat Reader. Do you get this problem for any other file type? We don't see a general problem with file associations on Windows 8.

Comment: Indeed, we tested with another extension ".xyd" and the association works.  However, I don't see why it would not work with .pdf files:  there is no "fighting" between applications, file association should just be a setting in the registry.  Is this a document feature in Windows 8, that it has preferred applications or something?

Comment: Additionally, we can still do the file association by right clicking on the file and choosing our application.  If this can be done through the GUI, then it should be possible to do it at install time.

Comment: Unfortunately, associating with an extension that is managed by an application like Acrobat Reader is often not successful. Our file association mechanism is straight-forward, but taking the association away from an application that does this differently is not handled in install4j. I'm not sure what could be special about Windows 8 in this regard.

Comment: I think that we're still missing something:  I don't believe that Adobe is using any different mechanism, as far as I know, they use the standard OS mechanism that every other application uses, and that I would think install4j uses.  This works without problems in all other OSs, it only fails on Windows 8.  The only explanation I think would be that Windows 8 made some changes / added some features, but then it should be documented and install4j should support it.

Comment: Any news on this?  If I can change the default program by right clicking on a file, regardless of the file extension, then this is possible, and install4j should support it.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't see any general problem with this on Windows 8, so we have no test case that we could fix.

Comment: Have you tried creating an install4j project that sets the file association for .pdf files?  We would be glad to send you the project and installer package, the problem happens every time.

Comment: As an aside, I do see that Windows 8 might have changed the way that file associations are handled, but it can be done, and I would expect, as a paying customer, that install4j would keep up with this.

Comment: As I said, we do not see any general problems with file associations on Windows 8 nor do we see any changes in the principal mechanisms in Windows 8. In your case there seems to be an interference with the way that Adobe Acrobat sets up its file associations.

Comment: I don't believe this:  Acrobat still have to go through the OS to setup file association, it is the OS that launches a program when a file is double clicked.  If I can create a file association through the OS using its GUI, then install4j should be able to do so as well.

Comment: You mention that "you do not see a general problem":  Have you tested a sample installation project that associates .pdf files yet?  It happens every time here and "we do see a general problem"

Comment: No response...   I guess it is time to look for a different installer, one that supports Windows 8.